# How do I uninstall a package with SCons?

Tags: scons

What is the Scons equivalent of `make uninstall` after having installed a package with `scons --prefix=$HOME/.local install`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To uninstall, just add the "clean" option:

```
scons -c --prefix=$HOME/.local install
```

Comment: in scons  v3.1.2 it results in 
`error: combining 'clean*' targets with other targets is not allowed`

Answer (score 0):

Go to the folder with the source files and run

```
sudo scons uninstall
```